# Getting Images in C/C++?

Tags: c, graphics, ubuntu

I was making a puzzle game just for fun using C. Can I use images in my coding as we can use in other languages like JavaScript by giving their location or path?

I am on a Ubuntu machine, GCC complier. I am not currently using a graphics library.

Comment: What operating system, are you using a graphics library already?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need some kind of GUI. Standard C libraries don't have any. On Ubuntu, you can use QT (http://qt.nokia.com/products/) or GTK (http://www.gtk.org/).

If you want to read images you also need library. Specify which image format you're interested in. There are literally hundreds of image libraries. For example: JPEG: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg/ , BMP: http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/

As you see, there's a lot of trouble to write even simple game with nice graphic user interface in C. C is good for fast computations and terminal programs. My advice: If you want to quickly develop nice looking game, consider using Java, Python or C++. Personally I prefer Java-writing windowed application is really quick and simple there.

Answer (score 0):

Book for help. http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/cips2ed.pdf

Comment: I am using ubuntu and gcc compiler.

Answer (score 0):

using c language you can read image file like this

```
int width, height;
unsigned char * data;
FILE * file;

file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
width = 1024;

height = 512;

data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );
//int size = fseek(file,);
fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );

fclose( file );
```

all the RGB value of image is store in a variable unsingned char *data but to use this variable to draw image I think you have to use OpenGL graphics library by texture mapping method.
There are other library also which provide a function to load image directly like SDL.So,I suggest you to use SDL library with c to make your game .